# What is the best way to implement alarm in C?

Tags: c, scheduling, clock

I'm going to implement an alarm, which alarm and do sth at midnight.

Looking for the efficient way, because it's the app on the tiny os.

Which is the best way that use resource less than other.
I found some several ways.

1. Use the CPU clock, clock()

   ```
   void wait ( int seconds )
   {
      clock_t endwait;
      endwait = clock () + seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
      while (clock() < endwait) {}
   }

   int main ()
   {
      int n;
      printf ("Starting countdown...\n");
      for (n=10; n>0; n--)
      {
         printf ("%d\n",n);
         wait (1);
      }
      printf ("FIRE!!!\n");
      return 0;
   }
   ```
2. the other ways is implementing of preemptive Scheduling using various interval
   if diff time is over 4 hour, then interval value would be 30 min or later.
   if diff time is under 5 min, then interval value would be 10.

Comment: What's up with [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html),
[`alarm()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/alarm.html), and
[`pause()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pause.html)? In particular, `pause()` does nothing until a signal interrupts the process, and you can arrange for `alarm()` to send a SIGALRM signal after a given time has elapsed (86400 seconds, less any processing time between invocations). This leaves the CPU available to do real work for other processes. A busy loop is a bda idea!

Comment: what OS is this? Different OSes may have different ways to do. There may be a timer built into the OS, or hardware RTCs/timers availables

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is totally correct in that you will want to register an interrupt based on a hardware timer, but the best way to do this may depend on your hardware. ie could require asm... I don't know TinyOS